# How to create a closure inside a closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a function in Swift so I can make a repeating animation (I know you can use `.repeat`, but I do not want to use that). In my `completion` closure, I am getting an error. Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

var withDurationVar:TimeInterval = 0
var optionsVar:UIViewAnimationOptions?
var iterateVar = 0
var animationsVar:(() -> ()?)?
var completionVar:(() -> ()?)?

var numberOfIterations = 0


func repeatingAnimation(withDuration:TimeInterval, options:UIViewAnimationOptions, iterate:Int, animations:@escaping () -> (), completion:@escaping () -> ()) {

    withDurationVar = withDuration
    optionsVar = options
    iterateVar = iterate
    animationsVar = animations
    completionVar = completion

}


func animationRepeat() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: withDurationVar, delay: 0, options: optionsVar!, animations: animationsVar as! () -> Void, completion: { (Finished) in

        // Increase number of iterations
        numberOfIterations += 1

        // If it has not yet done every iteration needed
        if numberOfIterations != iterateVar {

            // Repeat animation
            animationRepeat()

        }
        else {

            completionVar // Where I get an error.  'Expression resolves to an unused I-value'

        }

    })

}
```

I can do this however:

```
func animationRepeat() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: withDurationVar, delay: 0, options: optionsVar!, animations: animationsVar as! () -> Void, completion: completionVar)

}
```

So how can I have the `completion` from my `repeatingAnimation` function into the `completion` of `animationRepeat` with the rest of the code as well? Thanks!

Comment: _What_ error do you get?

Comment: `completionVar?()`.

Comment: @rmaddy Exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code if anyone want to use it as a repeating animation function :)

```
import UIKit

// Make some variables to be accessed across the file
var withDurationVar:TimeInterval = 0
var optionsVar:UIViewAnimationOptions?
var iterateVar = 0
var animationsVar:(() -> ()?)?
var completionVar:(() -> ()?)?

var numberOfIterations = 0


// The function to call
func repeatingAnimation(withDuration:TimeInterval, options:UIViewAnimationOptions, iterate:Int, animations:@escaping () -> (), completion:@escaping () -> ()) {

    // Set the global variables from the parameters
    withDurationVar = withDuration
    optionsVar = options
    iterateVar = iterate
    animationsVar = animations
    completionVar = completion

    // Has not started repeating yet
    numberOfIterations = 0

    // Start repeat
    animationRepeatForFunction()

}


// The function which is ONLY called by the repeatingAnimation or itself, not the user
func animationRepeatForFunction() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: withDurationVar, delay: 0, options: optionsVar!, animations: {animationsVar?()}, completion: { (Finished) in

        // Increase number of iterations
        numberOfIterations += 1

        // If it has not yet done every iteration needed
        if numberOfIterations < iterateVar {

            // Repeat animation
            animationRepeatForFunction()

        }
        else {

            // Perform what the user wanted to do after the repeating animation
            completionVar?()

        }

    })

}
```

Call the function using `repeatingAnimation(...)`

The `.repeat` function can only really be used for infinite loops, which do not need to be stopped. In my case, I wanted to repeat a finite amount of times (terminates), so I made this custom function which can have its own `.swift` file.

Comment: Your answer does not explain what was wrong and how this answer fixes the issue. Don't rely on the comments. Put all relevant info in the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I have put comments in the code, and explained why the original solution didn't work